# NullPointerException one more time - intersects()

Tags: java, multithreading

**Ball.java**

```
public class Ball {
    int x = 500, y = 10, speed = 1;
    GameBoard board;
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    Thread thread;

    Ball(GameBoard board) {
        this.board = board;
        new Thread(r1).start();
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (board.ball.intersects(board.pPaddle)) {
                        speed = -speed;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(board.ball + " z " + board.pPaddle);
                    }
                    x -= speed;
                    board.repaint();
                    Thread.sleep(10L);

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
            }
        }

    };
}
```

**GameBoard.java**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameBoard extends Canvas {
    Image dbi;
    Graphics db;
    JFrame okno;
    Player p = new Player(this);
     Ball b = new Ball(this);
     Ai a = new Ai(this);
     Rectangle aiPaddle = new Rectangle(10, 590, 10, 50);
     Rectangle pPaddle = new Rectangle(10, 100, 10, 50);
     Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(500, 10, 10, 10);
    GameBoard() {
        okno = new JFrame();
        okno.setTitle("Pink Ponk");
        okno.setSize(600, 300);
        okno.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        okno.setResizable(false);
        okno.setVisible(true);
        okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameBoard gra = new GameBoard();
        gra.okno.add(gra);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        pPaddle.setBounds(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        aiPaddle.setBounds(a.getX(), a.getY(), 10, 50);
        ball.setBounds(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        dbi = createImage(10, 50);
        db = dbi.getGraphics();
        paint(db);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
        g.drawRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.drawOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.fillOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        pPaddle.setBounds(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        aiPaddle.setBounds(a.getX(), a.getY(), 10, 50);
        ball.setBounds(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 50);
        g.drawOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
        g.fillOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 10, 10);
    }

}
```

It worked until I wrote this line of code (24 in Ball.java):

```
if (board.ball.intersects(board.pPaddle))
```

I'm getting error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Ball$1.run(Ball.java:24)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I'm sure that rectangles in GameBoard.java aren't empty. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please post your code in your question instead of providing links.

Comment: Next time I'll do like you said :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there are 2 possibilities:

- `board`, the argument passed to the Ball's constructor, is null
- `board`, the argument passed to the Ball's constructor, is not null but because you start a thread in the constructor, the thread can see your Ball object partially constructed (and for example, ball.board might have not been assigned yet)...

What you sould do:

1. Check that `board` is not null (with a print statement for example)
2. In any case, [don't start a new thread in your constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057510/java-starting-a-new-thread-in-a-constructor)

You can create the thread in the consctructor and provide another method (start or init for example) that starts the thread.

---

Once you have done that, you will probably not get your NPE any longer. However, note that the line `Ball b = new Ball(this);` is executed before `Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(500, 10, 10, 10);` so if you access `board.ball` in the Ball's constructor, you will see it null.

In general, you should avoid escaping `this` in the constructor or an instance initializer (i.e. don't write something like `ObjectXX o = new ObjectXX(this);`) because `this` might not be fully constructed.

Comment: After some testing, I'm inclined to believe that the latter option (board is partially constructed) to be true, this looks like a race condition in constructing and accessing object fields.

Answer (score 0):

The ball rectangle could very well be null, you first create the b which starts a thread which will try to access *board.ball*. *ball* is created later in the GameBoard constructor.