# Starting Threads In A Constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

It is said threads should NEVER be started in constructors, but I am not sure how `this` reference escapes the `Test` constructor in this case. I looked at the underlying Thread.java and I cannot figure this out.

```
class Test {

    static MyThread thread;

    public Test() {

        thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();

    }

}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        //do stuff

    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

`thread = new MyThread();` would call `Thread` super constructor:

```
public Thread() {
    init(null, null, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}
```

I do not see a reference getting away.

Comment: Making the thread static is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057510/java-starting-a-new-thread-in-a-constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` can only escape if the thread references `this` (eg, if it's an inner class)

Your thread does not reference `this`, so this is not an issue.

However, constructing an object is generally expected to be side-effect-free; this is not a good idea.

Comment: But books I read say you should never do this. Is this case ok then? EDIT: seems so seeing your edit.

Comment: @jsn: The books are correct; you should not do this, but not for that reason.